# Absolute Singleton for multiple classloaders in the same JVM

Tags: java, reflection, singleton, classloader

I am trying to build an RMI Client/Server in the same JVM but I am facing a problem while using the same Singleton instance for both Client and Server when running each of them. For both client and the server a distinct instance of my singleton is created. After reading a bit about the potential problems a developer may face while implementing the Singleton design pattern, I figured out that is mainly due to the different ClassLoaders of both Client and Server although they are running on the same JVM (Or there's may be some other reason I couldn't see?!). So after reading some recommended articles like [Singleton Pattern in Java](http://snehaprashant.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/singleton-pattern-in-java.html) and [Java Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html) I finally implemented this solution which I am not sure if it is the right way to do and which throws by the way an exception :

```
//This is the method used to get my Singleton (i.e: Controller) instance
public static Controller getInstance() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    Class obj = getClassLosader().loadClass(Controller.class.getName());//java.lang.ClassNotFoundException thrown here
    Method getInstanceMethod = obj.getDeclaredMethod("getInstanceSingleton", new Class[] { });      
    Object absoluteController = getInstanceMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] { } );
    return (Controller)absoluteController;      
}

public static Controller getInstanceSingleton(){
        if(controller==null)
            controller = new Controller();

        return controller;
}

private static ClassLoader getClassLosader() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    //ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    // doesn't solve the problem either      
    ClassLoader classLoader = Controller.class.getClassLoader().getParent();
    if(classLoader == null)
            classLoader = Controller.class.getClassLoader();
    return classLoader;
}
```

Any help will be more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *an RMI Client/Server in the same JVM* **Why**?

Comment: It's a game (An academic exercise). A proof of concept to say.

Comment: You're off in the weeds with your code.  If you're running in a single JVM for both client and server and don't play games with classloaders, then the standard Singleton pattern should work as long as it's written thread-safe... although, you should be using Dependency Injection instead

Comment: Singleton is almost always an anti-pattern. As @JimGarrison said, try refactoring your code to use plain old constructors or dependency injection instead. Also, why are you using reflection to just call a known method??

Comment: I was running out of time and I finished by using dependency injection. Although I still want to know how can we get the absolute Singelton instance object shared by different running processes (i.e: Different classloaders) in the same JVM. Still an unanswered question for me.